# GeoFire: How to add extra conditions within the query?

Tags: firebase, geofire

I am wondering if it is possible to add extra conditions to the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geofire can filter items by their distance to a given point. It cannot filter by any other conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!